# Firewalls vs DMZ

Tags: network, firewalls, dmz

What's the difference between Firewalls and DMZs?  These terms seem to overlap at time and I'm not clear on the difference. Maybe a DMZ is achieved using firewalls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply, a DMZ is portion of your network carved off and isolated from the rest of your network. A firewall is the appliance that creates that isolation, by restricting traffic both between the intranet and the DMZ and the DMZ and other networks it's exposed to.

Answer (score 1):

Firewall is a device.sometimes it can be a software as well.
DMZ is a Logical or Physical Network.

DMZ or demilitarized zone is a physical or logical subnetwork that contains and exposes an organization's external-facing services to an untrusted network, usually a larger network such as the Internet. Firewall can help to separate this network from your lan. *wiki*

A firewall is a network security system that monitors and controls incoming and outgoing network traffic based on predetermined security rules. A firewall typically establishes a barrier between a trusted internal network and untrusted external network, such as the Internet. *Wiki*